# jQuery deferred objects and callbacks

Tags: jquery, callback, deferred

I have the following simplified code:

```
$.when(someClass.MethodWithXhrCall(args, callBack, errCallBack))
.then(function () {
        console.log('Yep');
    }
})
.fail(function () {
    console.log('Nope');
});

function callBack(data) {
    // Yes I got my data
    var x=data.CustomerName;
    .....
}

function errCallBack(data) {
    alert (data.ErrorText);
}
```

The callbacks are not being called.  Yet, when I do not use the deferred construct, the callbacks work as expected.  Of course, I run into other timing issues, which I was trying to avoid using the deferred construct.

**Updated on 5/23/2013 [SOLVED] **
I was finally able to do what I was looking.  My callbacks are getting response objects, and the deferred object is blocking the code to be executed until the call is complete.

Here is the code:

```
// Define this as a global variable
var _eipDfd = null; // Will be used to create the deferred object

// Call the webservice to read this customer's data
console.log("Reading existing customer data");
function asyncEvent() {
    _eipDfd = new jQuery.Deferred();
    someClass.GetCustomer(args, processReadCust, errCallBack);
    return _eipDfd.promise();
}
$.when(asyncEvent()).then(
    function (status) {
        console.log(status); // Will print Success!!
    },
    function (status) {
        console.log(status); // Will print Failed :(
    }    
);    
console.log("Web service call is done");
......

// Callback functions are still being called from someClass.GetCustomer with the response object being pass to them
processReadCust: function (data) {
    // Do the work


    _eipDfd.resolve("Success!!");
    return;
}    

errCallBack: function (data) {
    // Take care of failure

    _eipDfd.reject("Failed :(");
    return;     
}
```

Comment: Does `someClass.MethodWithXhrCall()` return a promise or deferred object?

Comment: And why not just do : `someClass.MethodWithXhrCall(args).done(function(response) { ... });`

Comment: Or `someClass.MethodWithXhrCall(args).then(callBack, errCallBack);
`?

Comment: So, let us go with Beetroot's implementation:  

    someClass.MethodWithXhrCall(args).then(callBack, errCallBack);  

Question is: Will callBack and errCallBack have access to the returned data from the Ajax call?  

The reason for my question:  
Within someClass.MethodWithXhrCall(), I explicitly call with data as the argument:    

    callBack (data), or  
    errCallBack(data)   

If the answer is yes then problem solved.  If not then how can I pass that information to callBack or errCallBack functions?

Comment: I'll have to do this as a proper answer .....

Comment: I had already tried Adeneo's suggestion, the response object was not being passed to the callback, when used in done, then etc.  Kevin's suggestion led me to dig more and I found the solution.  It is my question itself since I cannot post answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck, the guys at jQuery designed jqXHR objects for exactly this scenario.

First, return a jqXHR object from `someClass.MethodWithXhrCall`, for example :

```
someClass.MethodWithXhrCall = function(...) {
    ...
    return $.ajax(...);
}
```

*Ajax shorthand methods `$.get()`, `$.getJSON()`, `$.getScript()` and `$.post()` also return a jqXHR object.*

Now, the same parameters will be passed to `callBack` as would be passed to a `$.ajax` success function. So write `callBack` as follows :

```
function callBack(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    ...
}
```

And similarly the same parameters will be passed to `errCallBack` as would be passed to a `$.ajax` error function. So write `errCallBack` as follows :

```
function errCallBack(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    ...
}
```

See the [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) page for more information.

Thus everything returned by the server is available to one or other of these two callbacks.

Any variables local (therefore private) to `someClass.MethodWithXhrCall` are not automatically available to the callbacks, however they can be passed through, with a little more work. Worry about this aspect only if necessary.